# Adding dummy elements to fill X number of spaces

Tags: php

Working on a webstore, that has a grid layout for products.

The grid default is 5 items across, and 4 down : 20 items.

With the CSS, the items `<li>` are justified to evenly space them out. However, when you have less than a multiple of 5 the spacing is skewed since the justified spacing has less than 5 items to space on that line thus adding more white-space. **SEE:** http://jsfiddle.net/DmgeF/1/

Now, I know how many products are listen per page using `$count_page = $wp_query->post_count`. At maximum I can list 200 items per page.

My idea is to add dummy `<li>` elements to the last line if it needs 1, 2, 3, or 4 extra `<li>`s to even out the spacing.

I have tried:

```
// GET MULTIPLES OF 5
$array_main = array_fill(1, 40, null);
array_walk($array_main, function(&$item, $key){ $item = $key * 5; });

// GET $array_main MINUS OTHERS
$minus_1 = $minus_2 = $minus_3 = $minus_4 = array();
foreach($array_main as $key => $value) {
    $minus_1[$key] = $value - 1 ;
    $minus_2[$key] = $value - 2 ;
    $minus_3[$key] = $value - 3 ;
    $minus_4[$key] = $value - 4 ;
}
```

Which results in the number of items minus the *n* value of missing `<li>`.

What I've been struggling to figure out is how to calculate the number of missing `<li>` I need.

Something like:

```
if($count_page IS A VALUE OF $minus_1) { echo '<li></li>'; }
if($count_page IS A VALUE OF $minus_2) { echo '<li></li><li></li>'; }
if($count_page IS A VALUE OF $minus_3) { echo '<li></li><li></li><li></li>'; }
if($count_page IS A VALUE OF $minus_4) { echo '<li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>'; }
```

Comment: @Ejay are you asking if `-moz-box-sizing` will work in other browsers than mozillaz's? If so then that's why there is the `-webkit-box-sizing` and `box-sizing` there.. If you're asking why http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/. If you're asking something different, could you rephrase?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `$minus_X` arrays? Some code that generates the markup (that's in JSFiddle) will be helpful.

Comment: @Ejay wanted to use them to see if the number of items on the page was in one of the arrays and echo out the correct li items. But Oswald totally made me dumbfounded how easy it was.

Comment: I misread ur css and tried to delete the comment immediately, but I think it was too late. I later ovserved the rest of `box-sizing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `5 - $count_page % 5` dummy list items to bring the total number of list items up to a multiple of 5, unless `$count_page % 5 == 0`, in wich case you do not have to add any dummy list items.

Comment: I seriously feel so dumbfounded on how easy that should have been.